# Eigen: Use SparseMatrix's selfAdjointView

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

According to the Eigen [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialSparse.html#TutorialSparse_TriangularSelfadjoint), I would expect the following to work:

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/Sparse"
SparseMatrix<double> mymatrix = SomeFunctionReturningASparseMatrix();

SparseMatrix<double> test = mymatrix.selfadjointView<Lower>();
```

However, I get the compile-time-error

```
conversion from 'Eigen::SparseSelfAdjointView<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 2u>' to 
non-scalar type 'Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>' requested
```

What am I doing wrong? Missing include?

Second question: As far as I was able to find, Eigen does not yet support multiplication of SparseSelfadjointViews with SparseMatrices. Am I missing something, or is this in fact not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member ggael in the Eigen forum was able to answer my question. For completeness, I will cite his answer here:

---

For the first issue, the following should do the job:

```
 SparseMatrix<double> test; 
 test = mymatrix.selfadjointView<Lower>();
```

For te second, you are right, such product is not supported.

---

The original question was posted and answered [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=108454&p=253073#p253073).

Answer (score 2):

Your function `mymatrix.selfadjointView<Lower>()` returns an object of type `SparseSelfAdjointView<SparseMatrix<double>, 2u>` and you are trying to cast it as a `SparseMatrix<double>` inside this line:

```
SparseMatrix<double> test = mymatrix.selfadjointView<Lower>();
```

You should also

```
#include <SelfAdjointView.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am pretty aware that I am doing a cast there. However, according to the documentation I linked in my first post, this cast should explicitly be allowed by Eigen. Furthermore, as far as I can see, the `SelfAdjointView.h` is about *dense* selfadjoint views, not the sparse ones.

Comment: What I saw is that your `selfAdjointView` object can be *multiplied* with `SparseMatrix` objects... Look here, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialSparse.html, at the bottom of the page

Comment: Yep, what I see there is multiplication with dense matrix objects, permutations and copy operations. As far as I can see I am doing copy operations as explained there.